# How to train intermediate filters/kernels in a stocastic spiking convolutional network using stdp?

Tags: unsupervised-learning, conv-neural-network

So I am working on building a spiking convolution network for image classification (currently MNIST). Up till now I have trained the 1st layer filters by providing patches (same size as the filter) of the image to the neurons of the hidden layer and using stdp and built the first layer of the convolutional network along with the subsampling/pooling layer.

Now the problem is that I want to learn the filters/kernels to form the feature maps for the next convolutional layer. So for this I was looking at this [paper](http://journals.plos.org/ploscompbiol/article?id=10.1371/journal.pcbi.0030031), which suggests using the method of weight sharing among the neurons of the same feature map to do so. But I don't want to use that as I want to make my system as distributed as possible meaning all the neurons are independent and communicate only through synapses and the same with the synapses. Thus I can't use weight sharing as it violates that goal.

Thus I wanted if anyone have any idea how could I approach this, and any papers that could lead me in the right direction.